# Privacy - Location Default Accuracy Reduced (NSLocationDefaultAccuracyReduced) Not respected

Tags: core-location

Setting `Privacy - Location Default Accuracy Reduced` in an apps `Info.plist` file and then calling `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` still asks for precise location permission from the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in Xcode, the plist editor sets `Privacy - Location Default Accuracy Reduced` to a string when it needs to be a boolean.

To work around this you can edit your plist as source code and then set it to:

```
<key>NSLocationDefaultAccuracyReduced</key>
<true/>
```

This will then only prompt for approximate accuracy.